# Running Python script through subprocess fails

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run util.py from script `file1.py` using `subprocess`. Both of them are in same directory. When I run them from current directory it works fine, but if I run `file1.py` from different directory it fails.

file1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
out=subprocess.Popen(["./util.py"],shell=True)
print "done"
```

util.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def display():
  print "displaying"
display()
```

error:

```
/bin/sh: ./util.py: No such file or directory
  done
```

Comment: Use complete route instead of `"./util.py"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing `./util.py` in a terminal means *"Look in the current working directory for a file named util.py and run it*." The working directory is the directory from where you run the command. This means that your python script cannot see util.py if you run it from a different directory.

If you are sure that file1.py and util.py always lie in the same directory, you could use `__file__` and `os.path.dirname` to prefix it with the directory of file1.py:

file1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess

current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "util.py")
out = subprocess.Popen([filename], shell=True)
print("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `execfile()` instead of `subprocess.Popen()`:

file1.py:

```
execfile("util.py")
print "done"
```

or if you want to process both of them,you can use `threading` module which is already in python's standard library:

```
from threading import Thread

Thread(target=lambda:execfile("util.py")).start()  
print "done"
```